# replace the value of data-href with the current url of the page every time button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Please tell me how to change the value of `data-href` when the button is pressed using php

```
<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://wishindia.in/wishindia/Diwali/index.php?name=Ram&amp;message=Jai+Shri+Ram"></div>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://wishindia.in/wishindia/Diwali/index.php?name=Mk&amp;message=Share+button" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwishindia.in%2Fwishindia%2FDiwali%2Findex.php%3Fname%3DMk%26message%3DShare%2Bbutton&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
```

Share on Whatsaps

```
<div id="mobile-share">
  <a href="whatsapp://send?text=http://wishindia.in/wishindia/Diwali/index.php?name=asdfa&message=asdfadf" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share on Whatsaps</a>
</div>


buttton
<a href="#" class="newwish" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send</a>
```

Comment: You can not do it with php, only with javascript. That only if you don't want to send him to another page where that page has the link automatically changed.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried. You will need JavaScript to change elements, not PHP. PHP can not change anything that is already displayed on a webpage.

Comment: you could probably just add some css code like so... method="get" onclick="document.location.href = 'this.data-href.value'; return false;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike X and Naltroc said you can do it using jQuery, here is an example code:

```
$(".fb-send").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();// this will stop redirecting to other page
    $(this).attr("href", "https://www.google.com");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" id="w3s">W3Schools.com</a></p>
 <button>Change href Value</button>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
        $("#w3s").attr("href", window.location.href);
     });
 });
 </script>
```

finaly i got my answer window.location.href with some jquery did that job perfectly.